# TRIAC BT136 as DIAC BD3 conversion both have MT1 and MT2

Tags: ac, triac, diac

A DIAC looks like a diode.

A TRIAC looks like transistor.

I have project that uses a DB3 and a BT136, but the BD3 is not available in the local market.

Can I cut the gate terminal off of a BT136 to make a BD3, just like we can make a "transistor as diode?" I have noted both (TRIAC/DIAC) have MT1 and MT2, where as TRAIC BT136 has an extra G terminal.

If the answer is no, how can I make alternative to a DIAC when it is not available?

Comment: a phase shifting RCRC dimmer pot to a small current bridge rectifier to an MC3021 Triac can trigger a Triac, but with this much trouble, DIAC’s make it easy, so just buy a dimmer.

Comment: Does the diac need to be bidirectional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Diac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIAC) and [Triac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC) work in different operating principles.

> DIAC (diode for alternating current) is a diode that conducts
> electrical current only after its breakover voltage.
>  TRIAC
> (triode for alternating current) is a component that conducts current
> in either direction when triggered.

Thus, it is not straight forward to replace a DIAC with a TRIAC, however possible it can be.

"**diode that conducts electrical current only after its breakover voltage**" is the keyword.

You may simply replace a Diac with two Zener diodes back to back in series. However, unlike a Diac, the voltage accross back-to-bak-Zener does not fallback after brakeover voltage reached.